# Calling a codebehind method from aspx page from gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How do you call a codebehind/class method from a gridview in an aspx page?  Also, I need to pass the value of databound column to that method.  Is this possible?

Something like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Precision" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="MyNumber" DataFormatString="FormatHelper.Format(MyNumber, Precision)" />
```

Comment: You need to provide more info. How are you getting the data in the first place? What exactly are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I tested this to work.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="My Number">
  <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Label runat="server" 
           Text='<%# Eval("MyNumber", FormatHelper.Format((decimal)Eval("MyNumber"), (decimal)Eval("Precision") )) %>' />

  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This works because the Eval method takes the `DataFormatString` as an optional second parameter. *note: Make sure you replace the casts with the appropriate types for the method signature.*

An easier way might be to bind to a linq-to-objects projection instead.

```
myGridView.DataBind( from foo in fooList
                     select new {
                       MyNumber = MyNumber,
                       Precision = Precision,
                       MyFormattedNumber = FormatHelper.Format(MyNumber, Precision),
                     } );
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of thing that I was looking for.  Will give this a try...

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this error: Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField does not have a DataBinding event.

Answer (score 1):

1. `GridView.DataKeys` Property
2. `Button.CommandArgument` Property

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a template field in the gridview.
2. Add a  button to the template field and give the button a
   commandName (example: "btn")
3. Handle the `rowdatabound` event and check if `rowType=DataRow` then:

   Get the button within this row using the `FindControl` method then
   fill in its `CommandArgument` the value you want(example: `e.Row.DataItem("ID")`)
4. Handle the `rowcommand` event:

   if commandname="btn" then
      the button is clicked